# Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent error

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sprite-kit

I am getting the error: "Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent" when trying to run my game.

If I add the SKSpriteNode locally into the function, it runs fine. But when I try and declare it globally, I get that error. Any help to resolve this error would be great. I assume it has to do with the             `self.bee.removeFromParent()` but I can't get it to work.

```
let bee = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Bee")

runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(
    SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.runBlock(addBee),
        SKAction.waitForDuration(0.5)
        ])
    ))

func addBee() {

    bee.name = "Bee"
    let actualY = random(min: 0, max: siz    e.height+bee.size.height ) // random

    bee.position = CGPoint(x: size.width + bee.size.width/2, y: actualY)
    self.addChild(bee)

    let slopeToPlayer = (bee.position.y - player.position.y) / (bee.position.x - player.position.x)
    let constant = bee.position.y - slopeToPlayer * bee.position.x

    let finalX : CGFloat = bee.position.x < player.position.x ? 500.0 : -500.0 // Set it to somewhere outside screen size

    let finalY = constant +  slopeToPlayer * finalX

    let distance = (bee.position.y - finalY) * (bee.position.y - finalY) + (bee.position.x - finalX) * (bee.position.x - finalX)
    let beeSpeed = random(min: CGFloat(50), max: CGFloat(150))
    let timeToCoverDistance = sqrt(distance) / beeSpeed

    let moveAction = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(finalX, finalY), duration: NSTimeInterval(timeToCoverDistance))
    let removeAction = SKAction.runBlock { () -> Void in
        self.bee.removeFromParent()
    }
    bee.runAction(SKAction.sequence([moveAction,removeAction]))


}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot add a single instance of the same `SKNode` twice. That is like saying a person can exist at two places at once.
When you create the `Bee node` globally,outside the scope of the `addBee`  function, you are trying to add the same instance of `Bee` again and again.

If you want to add multiple nodes, you should create separate instances of the nodes. This is why creating them locally from within the function works.

```
func addBee() {

    let bee = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Bee")
    bee.name = "Bee"
    addChild(bee)
}
```

To get a reference of the colliding nodes.

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    var bodyA : SKPhysicsBody!
    var bodyB : SKPhysicsBody!

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask
    {
        bodyA = contact.bodyA!
        bodyB = contact.bodyB!
    }
    else
    {
        bodyB = contact.bodyA!
        bodyA = contact.bodyB!
    }

    // The two nodes that have collided
    let node1 = bodyA.node 
    let node2 = bodyB.node

}
```

Comment: So how would I go about creating them globally so that I can reference them when writing the collision detection? The code you gave me is what I had previously and that works fine, but I can't reference bee in another function since it only exists in addBee().

Comment: you will get a reference of the node that is collided inside the `didContactBegin` function when its called from the SKPhysicsBody.node property. Isn't that enough?

Comment: Thanks for the help so far! I have been trying to add this code in for collision for the last few days and I just can't get it to work! All I want it to do for now is println("Game Over") when a collision between player and bee is detected.

Comment: set the `player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask` to beeCategory and `bee.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask`  to playerCategory and use the code i gave above.

Comment: Okay thanks, I think I have it now. However, now the bees and the bees are effected by physics and move and change course when the two separate bee objects collide. **EDIT** Fixed it, I left out `   bee.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None`