# Attempted to add a SKNode which already has a parent

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, game-development

Please help. I'm doing a game with Swift 4. I want to make a loop that creates random grounds(and coins together) at different heights as a player comes down. But I got the error message.

Thread 1: "Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent:  name:'(null)' texture:[ 'coin1' (359 x 357)] position:{865, 2030} scale:{1.00, 1.00} size:{100, 100} anchor:{0.5, 0.5} rotation:0.00"

```
class GameScene: SKScene...{ let platform = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ground") let coin = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "coin1") let coin2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "coin2")

enum bitmasks: UInt32 {
    case player = 0b1
    case platform = 0b10
    case coin


override func didMove(to view: SKView) { ... makePlatform() }

func makePlatform() { let platform = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ground") platform.position = CGPoint(x: GKRandomDistribution(lowestValue: 0, highestValue: 800).nextInt(), y: GKRandomDistribution(lowestValue: 1200, highestValue: 1225).nextInt() - Int(player.position.y - 1000))

coin.position = CGPoint(x: platform.position.x + 80, y: platform.position.y + 80) coin.zPosition = 6 coin.setScale(1)

addChild(coin)
addChild(platform) }

func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
if contactA.categoryBitMask == bitmasks.platform.rawValue && contactB.categoryBitMask == bitmasks.cameraLine.rawValue {
        contactA.node?.removeFromParent()
        makePlatform()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you creating `coin`? Can you show your code for where `coin` is created?

This problem often occurs when the programmer accidentally keeps trying to add the same sprite by having a loop that updates its position and add it via `addChild`, rather than creating a new sprite in each loop.

Does this solve your problem? :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28407033/1430420

Comment: Thank you for answering. I put a function "makePlatform" to make a platform. Later, I also wrote code for "coin" inside the makePlatform. so I put "addChild(platform)" and "addChild(coin)" in the same "makePlatform" function. Would this cause a problem?

I just want to create coins right on the platforms at random heights.
For example) first platform and coin at x: 10, y: 300, second platform and coin at x: 20, y: 0, third platform and coin at x: 0, y: -300
Please advise how I can write a code to generate these two at random heights.

Comment: Can you post your code where you define `coin`? Are you defining it as a global variable? If that’s the case, when you do `addChild` you’ll be adding something that already exists. You need to do `let coin = skSpriteNode…` within your `makePlatform` code so that the `coin` variable gets discarded (but not the sprite) when the function ends and calling the function again gets you a new `coin` so that the `addChild` is adding something new.